# Why sharded cluster mongodb slower than single mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I build Sharded Cluster mongodb in 3 servers and use ycsb tool to inset 1 million records to test the performance.

Each record contains 11 fields. (1 string, 10 binary), fields "_id" is key.
I use the command below to enable shard.

```
sh.shardCollection("ycsb.usertable", {_id: 1})
```

This is the test result.

**Single mongodb**

```
bin\ycsb.bat run mongodb -P workloads\workloada -p operationcount=1000000 -threads 200 -p mongodb.batchsize=1 -p mongodb.url="mongodb://ycsb:ycsb_1234@127.0.0.1:20017/ycsb"

[OVERALL], RunTime(ms), 99762
[OVERALL], Throughput(ops/sec), 10023
[INSERT], Operations, 1000000
[INSERT], AverageLatency(us), 19613
```

**Sharded Cluster**

```
bin\ycsb.bat run mongodb -P workloads\workloada -p operationcount=1000000 -threads 200 -p mongodb.batchsize=1 -p mongodb.url="mongodb://ycsb:ycsb_1234@[127.0.0.1:20020],[127.0.0.2:20020],[127.0.0.3:20020]/ycsb"

[OVERALL], RunTime(ms), 146067
[OVERALL], Throughput(ops/sec), 6846
[INSERT], Operations, 1000000
[INSERT], AverageLatency(us), 28239
```

I am confused why is the performance slower than single db architecture?

Here are my settings, kindly to provide any comments, thank you.

My server is Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 and the mongodb architecture as below.

```
Mongo DB version：4.2.24
Server address：127.0.0.1、127.0.0.2、127.0.0.3
Mongos port：20020
Config port：20010
Shard1 port：20001
Shard2 port：20002
Shard3 port：20003
```

[image]

**Config server config:**

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "/mongodb/config/config.log"
    logAppend: true
storage:
    dbPath: "/mongodb/config"
    engine: "wiredTiger"
    directoryPerDB: true
    wiredTiger:
        engineConfig:
            cacheSizeGB: 1
            directoryForIndexes: true
            statisticsLogDelaySecs: 0
        collectionConfig:
            blockCompressor: "snappy"
        indexConfig:
            prefixCompression: true
    journal:
        enabled: true
processManagement:
    fork: true
net:
    bindIp: 127.0.0.1 #other server would be 127.0.0.2, 127.0.0.3
    port: 20010
replication:
    oplogSizeMB: 1024
    replSetName: configrs
sharding:
   clusterRole: configsvr
```

**Shard conf**

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "/mongodb/shard1/shard.log"
    logAppend: true
storage:
    dbPath: "/mongodb/shard1"
    engine: "wiredTiger"
    directoryPerDB: true
    wiredTiger:
        engineConfig:
            cacheSizeGB: 1
            directoryForIndexes: true
            statisticsLogDelaySecs: 0
        collectionConfig:
            blockCompressor: "snappy"
        indexConfig:
            prefixCompression: true
    journal:
        enabled: true
processManagement:
    fork: true
net:
    bindIp: 127.0.0.1 #other server would be 127.0.0.2, 127.0.0.3
    port: 20001
replication:
    oplogSizeMB: 1024
    replSetName: shardrs1
sharding:
   clusterRole: shardsvr
```

**mongos conf**

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "/mongodb/mongos/mongos.log"
    logAppend: true
processManagement:
    fork: true
net:
    bindIp: 127.0.0.1 #other server would be 127.0.0.2, 127.0.0.3
    port: 20020
sharding:
    configDB: configrs/127.0.0.1:20010,127.0.0.2:20010,127.0.0.3:20010
```

Comment: It is a common misunderstanding that IP `127.0.0.1` is your loopback IP. In fact it is `127.0.0.0/8`, i.e. **every** IP-Address between `127.0.0.1` and `127.255.255.254` points to your loopback, which means it is all the same! I would suggest to use real hostnames or just `localhost` if you run it on a single host for testing and development.

Comment: You would need to provide more details of your test. When you create a new sharded collection, then initially all documents are inserted into the [primary shard](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharded-cluster-shards/#primary-shard). If the amount of data is more than default chunks size (16 MiByte or 64 MiByte in current release of MongoDB), then the [balancer](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharding-balancer-administration/) jobs starts to distribute the data across the shards. This may impact your overall performance but it is also time dependent.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit 127.0.0.1~3 is just an example to explain my confusion. the actual ip is start with 10.x.x.x.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit What detail you want to know? I will glad to provide. and I've tried stop balancer, but the performance still slower than single db. runtime(ms): 141826 / Throughput(ops/sec): 7050

Comment: I would insert a few million documents (because the chunk size is rather big, thus you need some data to distribute the data across the shards), and wait for the balancer to be finished. What is the sharding key and how does your test data look like?

Comment: What is `statisticsLogDelaySecs: 0`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I just add more test detail in my post. "statisticsLogDelaySecs" seems related with output wiredTiger log, set 0 would disable the function.

Comment: Shard key `_id` is rather bad, see [Monotonically Changing Shard Keys](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharding-choose-a-shard-key/#monotonically-changing-shard-keys). All documents are inserted into the same shard, thus you don't gain any benefit from sharding. Instead you create additional load to your cluster.